# Tensor product of varieties : What's this notation $V_1\otimes V_2$?

Tags: notation, definition, universal-algebra

I saw this notation $V= V_1\otimes V_2$ in a survey on universal algebra, where $V$ was a variety, but the survey in question didn't define this notation. Could anyone explain what it means ?

Comment: I know what a variety is. As for the first link, you think it might be the product of $V_1$ and $V_2$ in the category of categories ? Why wouldn't it be $V_1\times V_2$ then ?

Comment: See also [Tensor product of groups](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_groups) and George Bergman, [An Invitation to General Algebra and Universal Constructions](https://books.google.it/books?id=9UGMBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA75), Springer (2015).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would have to read the survey in question to be sure, but I have most commonly seen this notation used when talking about decidable varieties.

You can find a definition here: https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~snburris/htdocs/MYWORKS/PAPERS/DecidVar.pdf

Comment: Thank you, I think this is it (the survey also mentions subvarieties and the term denoted $b$ in the link you provided)

Answer (score 3):

The tensor product notation, $V_1\otimes V_2$, for some kind of product of varieties is used in (at least) two different ways.

**Way 1.**

For the Kronecker product, or tensor product. ($V_1\otimes V_2$ is the variety of $V_1$ models in $V_2$, and conversely.) You can find it used this way here

*Freyd, P.
Algebra valued functors in general and tensor products in particular.
Colloq. Math. 14 1966 89-106.*

in the language of algebraic theories, and here

*Neumann, Walter D.
Malʹcev conditions, spectra and Kronecker product.
J. Austral. Math. Soc. Ser. A 25 (1978), no. 1, 103-117.*

in the language of varieties. The notation $V_1\otimes V_2$ is still used to denote the tensor product of varieties.

**Way 2.**

$V_1\otimes V_2$ has been used to denote the categorical product in the category of varieties and clone morphisms. This product of the varieties $V_1$ and $V_2$ is the variety whose clone is the product of the clone of $V_1$ with the clone of $V_2$. I have seen it denoted by $V_1\otimes V_2$, or by $V_1\widehat{\times}V_2$, or by $V_1\times V_2$ in, for example,

*García, O. C.; Taylor, W. The lattice of interpretability types of varieties. Mem. Amer. Math. Soc. 50 (1984), no. 305, v+125.*

*McKenzie, Ralph A new product of algebras and a type reduction theorem. Algebra Universalis 18 (1984), no. 1, 29-69.*

*Grätzer, G.; Lakser, H.; Płonka, J.
Joins and direct products of equational classes.
Canad. Math. Bull. 12 1969 741-744.*

Fortunately, the use of $V_1\otimes V_2$ in the sense of Way 2 seems to be dying out, and instead $V_1\times V_2$ is being used for the categorical product.